# Why F5 Big IP CLI self created file script doesn't work, although command works from terminal?

Tags: shell-script, arch-linux

Here's my script which is saved as f5cli and chmod +x f5cli for executable.
I'm using F5FPC_HOST environment variable to pick the value for host url

```
#!/bin/sh

user=$(echo "" | dmenu -p "Enter user:")
secret="'$(echo "" | dmenu -P -p  "Enter secret(PIN, OTP, Password):")'"

f5fpc --start -u $user -p $secret -t $F5FPC_HOST
```

Replacement of variable values is not a problem, i have verified by printing the data in echo/notify-send. I have tried changing bin/sh to bin/zsh or bin/bash.

Command which works in terminal

```
f5fpc --start -u user -p 'XXXX123456PASSWORD' -t https://abc.com
```

Comment: Explain what you mean by "doesn't work". Are you sure F5FPC_HOST is set correctly when the script doesn't work?

Comment: How do you call the script? What error message do you get?

Comment: That you use single quotes around your password in the command line doesn't mean you should single quotes in the variable (`secret="'$(...`). That should just be `secret=$(....)` and in the command line you should use `"$secret"`.

Comment: @berndbausch For some reason, logon fails. That's what i mean by doesn't work. yes F5FPC_HOST holds correct value, its exported in my zprofile. I have verified it.

Comment: @pfnuesel I call it either from my `st` terminal or from dmenu. Invoking is not an issue. Do you forsee any other issue?

Comment: @muru thats how i started with it, but when it didn't work, i changed it to what you see now.

Comment: I'm not familiar with dmenu. Can you print out variables, and see if they are correct? I.e. add something like `echo "User: $user - PW: $password"` before you call `f5fpc` and see if you get the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```bsh
user="$(printf "" | dmenu -p "Enter user:")"
pass="$(printf "" | dmenu -P -p "Enter secret(PIN, OTP, Password):")"

f5fpc --start -u "$user" -p "$pass" -t "$F5FPC_HOST"
```

Using `printf ""` to prevent dmenu to read stdin as a list. `echo` will append a new-line character, and `dmenu` will see that as an empty list entry.

Beside that you should check if `f5fpc` overwrites the password in argv - so that it is not revealed by using for example `ps`.

It could be better to open that script in a shell and let `f5fpc` as for password if that is the case.

Answer (score -1):

Got the fix. Thanks [Muru](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/70524/muru) for pointing the quote issue.

```
#!/bin/sh

user=$(echo "" | dmenu -p "Enter user:")
secret="$(echo "" | dmenu -p  "Enter secret(PIN, OTP, Password):")"

cmd="f5fpc --start -u $user -p '$secret' -t $F5FPC_HOST"

eval "$cmd"
```

Comment: Why switch to `eval`? Don't use it.

Comment: And, as muru said, you should use ``"$secret"``, not ``'$secret'``.  Also ``"$user"`` and ``"$F5FPC_HOST"``.

Comment: @pfnuesel what’s wrong with eval?